# Jest: How to mock a redux thunk calling another thunk?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs

I have the following redux thunk:

```
function thunkOne() {
    return dispatch => {
        callToApi().then(() => {
            dispatch(someNonThunkAction());
            dispatch(thunkTwo());
        });
    }
}

function thunkTwo() {
   return dispatch => {
      anotherCallToApi.then(dispatch(someOtherAction()));
   }
}
```

I would like to test only `thunkOne` and mock `thunkTwo` so that it doesn't get executed when I test `thunkOne`.

I tried to do this but it doesn't work:

```
import * as someActions from './actions';

it ('thunkOne should dispatch someNonThunkAction and thunkTwo', () => {
    someActions.thunkTwo = jest.fn();
    const expectedActions = [
            { type: SOME_NON_THUNK_ACTION, data: {} }
        ],
        store = mockStore(initialState);

    store.dispatch(someActions.thunkOne()).then(() => {
        expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
        expect(someActions.thunkTwo).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    someActions.thunkTwo.mockRestore();
});
```

I get the following error when I run this test:

> [ERROR] Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

How do I mock `thunkTwo` and test `thunkOne` only?

Comment: a blog post that talks about this: https://medium.com/@ferrannp/unit-testing-with-jest-redux-async-actions-fetch-9054ca28cdcd

Comment: Thanks but the case presented in that blog is not the same as mine - in his example, his thunk is calling a non async action. In mine, one async action is calling another async action.

Comment: not sure if that matters, did you try it?

Comment: It doesn't apply directly to your question, but your current test tests nothing. The `expect` statements are written inside `then` callback but you don't instruct Jest that it should wait for the Promise to be resolved.
You can easilly check it by adding `expect.assertions(2);` at the beginning of the test.
To make it work you should return the promise from the test or use async/await syntax.

Comment: Also I it loogs like that you get an error because you didn't create a mock store instance with a thunk middleware.